# unable to convert protobuf binary file to json in python - bytes' object has no attribute 'DESCRIPTOR'

Tags: python, json, protocol-buffers

employees.proto file,  compiles with protoc easily. and I import the resulting code into my own python code file as below.

```
syntax = "proto3";
package empList;

message Employee {
    int32 id = 1;
    string name = 2;
    float salary = 3;
}

message Employees {
    repeated Employee employees = 1;
}
```

Python file to add data and convert binary file to json.

````
import employees_pb2 as Test
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToDict
def main():
    emps = Test.Employees()
    obj1 = emps.employees.add()
    obj1.id = 10
    obj1.name = "Suresh"
    obj1.salary = 1000
    
    print(emps)
    with open("./serializedFile", "wb") as fd:
        t = emps.SerializeToString()
        fd.write(t)
        json_msg_string = MessageToDict(t, preserving_proto_field_name = True) 
        print("jsonSting : ", json_msg_string)
    empsRead = Test.Employees()
    with open("./serializedFile", "rb") as rfd:
        bstr = rfd.read()
        print(bstr)
        empsRead.ParseFromString(bstr)
    print(empsRead)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```
On running, I get the following traceback and I have been unable to understand the why I get the error of "AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'DESCRIPTOR". Error is in the comment.
````

Comment: File "C:\protobuf\convert.py", line 30, in main
    json_msg_string = MessageToDict(t, preserving_proto_field_name = True)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\json_format.py", line 168, in MessageToDict
    return printer._MessageToJsonObject(message)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\json_format.py", line 203, in _MessageToJsonObject
    message_descriptor = message.DESCRIPTOR
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'DESCRIPTOR'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```py
MessageToDict(emps, preserving_proto_field_name = True)
```

[`MessageToDict`](https://googleapis.dev/python/protobuf/latest/google/protobuf/json_format.html#google.protobuf.json_format.MessageToDict) takes the protobuf message (`emps`).

Comment: Thanks @DazWilkin it worked. Now I am kicking myself, why I did'nt think of that :-)