# How can I convert a PredictResponse to JSON?

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have a VertexAI project I want to access. I'm currently trying two approaches, via a React frontend and via a Python backend, which I would then connect to the FE. I posted a question about making requests to VertexAI from Node [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78208092/how-to-send-a-request-to-a-vertexai-model-from-nodejs).

In the python approach, I'm able to make the request and receive the correct response. However, in order for it to be accessible by the FE, I would need to convert it to JSON. I'm struggling with how to do that.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
# The AI Platform services require regional API endpoints.
client_options = {"api_endpoint": api_endpoint}
# Initialize client that will be used to create and send requests.
# This client only needs to be created once, and can be reused for multiple requests.
client = PredictionServiceClient(
    client_options=client_options, credentials=credentials
)
instance = schema.predict.instance.TextClassificationPredictionInstance(
    content=content,
).to_value()
instances = [instance]
parameters_dict = {}
parameters = json_format.ParseDict(parameters_dict, Value())
endpoint = client.endpoint_path(
    project=project_id, location=compute_region, endpoint=endpoint_id
)
response = client.predict(
    endpoint=endpoint, instances=instances, parameters=parameters
)
response_dict = [dict(prediction) for prediction in response.predictions]
```

`response_dict` is printable, but I can't convert `response` to json using `json.dumps` because:

```
TypeError: Object of type PredictResponse is not JSON serializable
```

This is the error that has been plaguing me in every attempt. DuetAI simply tells me to use `json.dumps`.

**EDIT**

Here's the working code using the accepted response:

```py
    ...
    response = client.predict(
        endpoint=endpoint, instances=instances, parameters=parameters
    )

    predictions = MessageToDict(response._pb)
    predictions = predictions["predictions"][0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `json.dumps` requires serialization of your response/s,  I believe it's better to use [`json_format.MessageToDict`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73588294/unable-to-convert-protobuf-binary-file-to-json-in-python-bytes-object-has-no?rq=3) instead of `json_format.ParseDict`.

They work quite the opposite:

- `ParseDict` takes a JSON dictionary representation and merges it into a pre-existing Protobuf message object. It parses the JSON data and populates the corresponding fields in the Protobuf message.
- `MessageToDict` takes a Protobuf message object and converts it into a Python dictionary representation which can then be easily serialized to JSON using `json.dumps`.

I found some online resources which discuss the `MessageToDict` function of the protobuf library. Please check them out for more information.

- [Unable to convert protobuf binary file to json in python - bytes' object has no attribute 'DESCRIPTOR'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73588294/unable-to-convert-protobuf-binary-file-to-json-in-python-bytes-object-has-no?rq=3)
- [JSON to Protobuf in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60345426/json-to-protobuf-in-python?rq=3)
- [Unable to parse Vertex job responses lack](https://cloud.google.com/knowledge/kb/unable-to-parse-vertex-job-responses-lack-000004947)

Comment: Thanks! I ended up going with a hacky way of converting the result to a string and then doing json.loads. I'm gonna replace that code with this and try it out.